# Using class/object between two forms

Tags: c#

I defined a class in Form1 as

```
    public class Conditions
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int probability { get; set; }
        public DateTime start_time { get; set; }
        public DateTime end_time { get; set; }
        public int age_min { get; set; }
        public int age_max { get; set; }
        public bool meldpeld { get; set; }
        public bool onea { get; set; }
        public bool oneb { get; set; }
        public int gender { get; set; }  // 0 - both, 1 - male, 2 - female
        public int meld_min { get; set; }
        public int meld_max { get; set; }

    }
```

and I'm making a new list like

```
    List<Conditions> newconditions = new List<Conditions>();
```

Then, I'm calling Form2 with

```
        Conditions newconds = new Conditions();
        Form2 form2 = new Form2(newconds);
        form2.Show();
        form2.TopMost = true;
```

In Form2, I have

```
    public Form2(Form1.Conditions newcond)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 2;
    }
```

and I can use set things for newcond in there

what I would like to do, however, is set things in another function in Form2 called

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

and I can't figure out how to use the newcond in that function. I must be missing something obvious, right?

Also, is this a good way to go? Basically what I want to do is have the user define any number of conditions (that they can add, edit, delete) and then use those conditions when they run the program.

Thanks

Comment: In Form2 you need to declare a field which will hold the value of the conditions passed through from Form1 - then in button2_Click this field will be accessible

Comment: In addition to my answer below, you should learn to use naming conventions so that your code can easily be understood by other developers and yourself. This page is a good start: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're on the right track sort of.

Basically, I would move your Conditions class into it's own file called Conditions.cs - this is best practice.

Then define a member variable in your class file for Form2. Then in your Constructor for Form2 set that member variable.

```
private Conditions _conditions;
public Form2(Conditions cond)
{
    _conditions = cond;
    InitializeComponent();
    comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 2;
}
```

then you can use that in your click method:

```
protected void button2_click(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    //Do things with _conditions
}
```

Comment: Yep, I was just about to write that. However, I did this: Form1.Conditions test = newcond; in the public Form2 class and then defined public Form1.Conditions test; outside of it and it's working.

Answer (score 1):

You're most of the way there.  You just need to make an instance field (or possibly a property) that can store the `Conditions` object.  In the constructor set that field based on the parameter and then use it in the event handler.